# is there anyway to visualize the categorical data in pandas dataframe in a intereactive way in a tabular format?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

[image: Data is as below]

Goal is to create a table that has the name from 1 to 20 with the color coded green means Breakfast and lunch yellow means either one of them and red means the person didn't have any meals. it is much easy to do in tableau however is there a way to do in python?

Below is the expected[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A heat map is a way to show your expected tables in a tabular format. Convert the Boolean values to integers and transform them into a matrix of the expected output. Then add up each column to get the values for the graph. For color coding, create a map with normalized values and assign colors.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

customdata = np.dstack((df['breakast'].to_numpy().reshape(4,5), df['Lunch'].to_numpy().reshape(4,5)))

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    z = df['breakast'].to_numpy().astype(int).reshape(4,5) + df['Lunch'].to_numpy().astype(int).reshape(4,5),
    text=df['Name'].to_numpy().reshape(4,5),
    customdata=customdata,
    texttemplate="%{text}",
    hovertemplate="breakast:%{customdata[0]}<br>Lunch:%{customdata[1]}<extra></extra>",
    textfont={"size":20},
    colorscale=[[0,'red'],[0.5,'orange'],[1,'green']],
))
fig.update_traces(showscale=False)
fig.update_yaxes(autorange='reversed', showgrid=False, showticklabels=False, visible=False)
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, showticklabels=False, visible=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how would you add extra hover information like additional column info if there are other information that you would like to show

Comment: The examples in the [references](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#adding-other-data-to-the-hover-with-customdata-and-a-hovertemplate) will be helpful. I have updated the code by adding your data columns as custom data as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

yellow = '#F4E04D'
red = '#D63230'
green = '#3A7D44'
data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Beth'],
    'Breakfast': [True, False, False, True],
    'Lunch': [True, False, True, False]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def save_dataframe_as_png(df, filename):
    #compute colors
    names = []
    colors = []
    for _ , row in df.iterrows():
        if row['Breakfast'] and row['Lunch']:
            color = green
        elif row['Breakfast'] or row['Lunch']:
            color = yellow
        else:
            color = red
        names.append(row['Name'])
        colors.append(color)

    #compute table layout
    num_cols = min(math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(names))), 5)
    num_rows = math.ceil(len(names)/num_cols)
    num_empty_cells = max(0, num_cols*num_rows - len(colors))

    for _ in range(num_empty_cells):
        names.append('')
    names = [names[i:i+num_cols] for i in range(0, len(names), num_cols)]

    _ , ax = plt.subplots()

    #create table
    table = ax.table(cellText=names, loc='center', cellLoc='center')
    table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    table.set_fontsize(10)
    ax.axis('off')

    default_color = '#FFFFFF'
    
    #set background color
    for i in range(num_cols):
        for j in range(num_rows):
            if i * num_cols + j < len(colors):
                cell = table.get_celld()[i, j]
                cell.set_facecolor(colors[i * num_cols + j])
            else:
                cell = table.get_celld()[i, j]
                cell.set_facecolor(default_color)

    plt.savefig(filename)


save_dataframe_as_png(df, 'table.png')
```